# How to watch multiple directories with WatchService?

Tags: java, nio, watchservice

I don't understand, how does

```
watcher.take();
```

will know about which directory to report? Does it report about each directory it was registered against?

```
dir.register(watcher...
```

If I have multiple watchers, will they report only about those directories, which were registered against them?

What is the purpose of return value of [register()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#register-java.nio.file.WatchService-java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind...-)? It looks like it never used in description here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `Path` to [`register`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#register-java.nio.file.WatchService-java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind...-) a file located by that `Path` to a `WatchService`.

If an event occurs, it will be enqueued in the `WatchService` and you can retrieve it with [`take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take--). `take()` has no idea about the actual `Path`.

Yes, a `WatchService` will only report events for those `Path`s registered with it.

You can use the `WatchKey` returned by the `register` method to compare against the `WatchKey` returned by `take()`. You can also, obviously, do all [the things described in the javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html)

Comment: What is the sense of comparing watchkey returned by register and returned by take?

Comment: @SuzanCioc It's an identifier. Instead of getting the `Watchable` from the `WatchKey`, you can just compare it directly, say you had some special behavior for one of the registered `Watchable`s.

Comment: Don't understand. Will watch keys equal in some cases? In which ones?

Comment: @SuzanCioc When you `register` a `Path`, you get back a `WatchKey`. If a watched event occurs for that same `Path`, `take()` will return the same `WatchKey` instance.

Answer (score 0):

We need to register the Folder F1 and all of it subFolders F11 and F12 recursively.
And the solution is provided in the official doc itself.

Here's the code segment you need to recursivly folder F1 and all of its subfolder to watchService:

```
/**
 * Register the given directory and all its sub-directories with the WatchService.
 */
private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
    // register directory and sub-directories
    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
            dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

    });

}
```

Incase of more details or incase you dont understand the usage of this code segment. refer to official doc. links provided below.

Official Doc Ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java